# How to access the value of a single datum in a dataset using an expression in Vega Lite

Tags: powerbi, vega-lite, vega, powerbi-custom-visuals, deneb

We are attempting to parameterize the y-axis domain range by allowing the user to create simple measures (y_min=0.3, y_max=0.7) in PowerBI, and then access these measures within the Vega-lite JSON code to set these scales.

I am able to set the raw values in the JSON, but want to grab the value of the measure in Deneb and assign it to a parameter. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you add a sample .pbix to illustrate the problem? It is difficult to understand at the moment.

Comment: @DavidBacci I can try to send something over, but basically just want to set a constant variable as a PowerBI measure (example measure: y_min=0.7) and then get the value of that measure in the vega-lite code. Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload a .pbix to an external site and link here. However, in answer to your question, the measure needs to be added to the data table supplied to Deneb. When creating a new Deneb visual, a good rule of thumb is to create a table of all the values that will be passed to Deneb before converting the table visual to a Deneb visual. If the measure is part of that original table visual, then it can be extracted and used in your spec.

**EDIT**
In this example, I have create a param with an expression to get the first row and then symbol value of "GOOG" and called my param d. You should be able to do the same using the correctly named dataset and column name. You don't need a param and can just use an expression but I don't know for sure as you haven't said whether this is Vega or VL.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {"url": "data/stocks.csv"},
  "transform": [{"filter": "datum.symbol==='GOOG'"}],
  "params": [{
    "name": "d",
    "expr": "data('source_0')[0].symbol"
  }],
  "mark": "line",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal"},
    "y": {"field": "price", "type": "quantitative"}
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: That's my current issue -- I have the measure added in the table, but for some reason I am unable to grab the raw value of the measure in the vega-lite. I am trying to do the following:
{
      "mark": {
        "type": "bar",
        "tooltip": true,
        "width": {"band": 0.7},
        "color": {"expr": "pbiColor(0)"}
      },
"encoding": {
        "y": {
          "field": "Actual",
          "scale": { 
            "domain": [0, "ymax"]
          }
        }

where ymax is a measure set in DAX / pbi to 5000, but it is not being put into the domain as 5000

Comment: Add a sample .pbix and expected output and I'll be happy to take a look. ymax will presumably appear multiple times (once for each record) so which record is it? Or if they're all the same, you need to just pick the first using an expression.

Comment: sorry, I am very new to this site and still trying to upload a pbix, but you are correct, they do appear multiple times and they are all the same, so we just need to pick the first using an expression. I have tried to do "domain": [0, {"expr":"Y_AXIS_MAX"}], but I am getting an error of "Unrecognized signal name: Y_AXIS_MAX"

Comment: It is hard to help without seeing a spec. Upload your .pbix to an external hosting site and the update your question with the link.

Comment: I'll add an update to my answer now to show you something that may help. Let me know if it does.